# VB for excel - having trouble with print control

Tags: excel, vba

newbie help needed.  I have an excel sheet set up with code to toggle cells against lines adjacent - the final result is so we can click the cells and it will only print the lines adjacent if they are toggled on (there are over 500 rows and not all are needed each project - a project "to do" list).  The cells to toggle are in columns 5 thru 8 (columns E:H).  I am struggling to get the print macro to work - particularly the bolded code where it refers to the row and columns i would like to have it look to.  Here is the printing code:

```
'------------------------------------------------
Sub PrintTickedRows()
    Dim MyRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    '--------------------
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MyRow = 5 - 8
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    '- hide rows
    For MyRow = 5 - 8 To LastRow
        **If ActiveSheet.Cells(MyRow, 5 - 8).Value = "" Then**
            ActiveSheet.Rows(MyRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
    '- print
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    '- make rows visible again
    For MyRow = 5 - 8 To LastRow
            ActiveSheet.Rows(MyRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------
```

The original code was written to work with multiple rows but only one column -
i have multiple columns that toggle.  The toggling code works.  Can someone help me through this one as i think i'm on the cusp but cant leap over this print code (i have as of this morning only 4 hours of coding experience) :)

Still a little trouble - here are the edits you suggested but at the end i'm still hung up on the proper code....

```
'------------------------------------------------
Sub PrintTickedRows()
    Dim MyRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Mycol As Integer
    '--------------------
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Mycol = 5
    For Mycol = 5 To 8
    MyRow = 1
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    '- hide rows
    For MyRow = 1 To LastRow
          If ActiveSheet.Cells(MyRow, Mycol).Value = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(MyRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
    '- print
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    '- make rows visible again
    For MyRow = 1 To LastRow
            ActiveSheet.Rows(MyRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the excel sheet screen shot if that helps:

[image: ***here is the excel sheet screen shot if that helps]

Comment: Is your goal to hide a row if **all** cells in columns E:H of that row are blank, or to hide a row if **any** cells in columns E:H of that row are blank?

Comment: Columns E thru H are check box cells - if they are not checked cell then i don't want the row to print.  We have lets say 800 rows and for some projects we only need 30 or so rows to print if they are checked.  I'll attempt to post to my quesiton what the excel sheet looks like to give a better idea...but i'm new here so i may mess that up

Comment: It's still not clear whether you are trying to print rows that have ticks in all cells, or whether to print rows that have at least one tick.  I.e. Should row 10 in your image be printed or not?

Comment: Also, you seem to have "heading" rows (e.g. "DIVISION 03 - CONCRETE").  Will those rows ever have ticks in them?  Should those rows ever be printed?

Comment: ticks only in the last 4 columns are the rows i'd like to have printed - the last code i posted goes up to the top and highlights yellow the first line. the excel sheet i posted - for example would only print that one line.  If any of those 4 cells are clicked i'd like that line to print. I'm sure it has to do with how i end it all but this is really foreign to me...i know we are close!

Comment: the heading rows i was thinking i would tick those as the default template and change the cell to white or something so they printed but didn't show up..basically the code doesn't have to address those lines...yes row 10 would be the one that would print in that example - including the columns ticked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to hide all rows, then unhide the rows that have at least one tick in them:

```
Sub PrintTickedRows()
    Dim MyRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MyCol As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Hide all rows from row 5 to the last used row
        .Rows("5:" & LastRow).Hidden = True

        For MyRow = 5 To LastRow
            For MyCol = 5 To 8
                ' Use 
                'If .Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Value = "" Then
                ' if your cells contain formulas to generate the ticks, otherwise
                ' you can just test whether the cell is empty
                If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Value) Then
                    .Rows(MyRow).Hidden = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next

        '- print
        .PrintOut

        '- make rows visible again
        .Rows("5:" & LastRow).Hidden = False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found you are so confused declaring values of variables.
If you set `MyRow = 5 - 8`, then the value of `MyRow` is -3.
My suggestion is to create a new variable for columns.

```
Dim MyCol  as Integer

MyCol = 5 'This should start your loop in column E
'Then create a loop for your column
For MyCol = 5 to 8 'This loop will work from Column E to Column H
   For MyRow = 5 To LastRow 'Define your initial Row, I'm supposing is 5.
       If Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Value = "" Then
           ActiveSheet.Rows(MyRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True 'You don't need to validate other columns?
       End If
   Next 'End of Row Loop
Next  ' End of Column Loop
```

Hope this example helps you to modify your code.

Comment: Making sense now on the subtracting and setting column variables...still something off.  Here is the current code..have to figure out how to post that code again...stand by :(

Comment: Update your question with your findings, new code and new questions.

Comment: okay..how the heck to i update the question...i'm sorry - punchy from early morning

Comment: @DavidG. `MyCol = 5 'This should start your loop in column E` is unnecessary, as `For MyCol = 5 to 8` will start by setting `MyCol` to the value `5`.

Comment: @YowE3K there are several things unnecessary in the code, but I'm trying to explain how to set variables values. I detected PM201 is really newbie. Why you are always looking for something wrong in my answers instead to post a new one?

Comment: complete newbie..adequacy not elegance at this stage :)

Comment: @DavidG. Sorry, wasn't trying to criticise you, just to help improve your answer.  I was worried that the OP might think that they needed to initialise the loop counter prior to the loop, rather than understanding that the `For` loop **itself** initialises the counter.  And I'm certainly not picking on you specifically - I usually don't look at who the answerer is before I comment.  (Except, if I do notice that it is Scott or Mat's Mug or similar, I rip their answers to shreds just to keep them on their toes ;) )

Comment: @YowE3K Please answer PM201 question. I detect you have more experience than I and you could provide a solution.

Comment: i put a screen shot up of the excel sheet

Comment: @DavidG. As far as I can see, your answer already answers the question ... unless the OP is trying to only hide rows if **all** cells in the row are blank.  Just waiting for confirmation from the OP re that to decide whether to uv your answer or to suggest an alternative.